# Only a small part of an image shows

Tags: html, css, image, button

So I have two images as buttons on a tool bar. For some reason that is unknown to me, only a small section of the images stays visible. Correct me if I'm wrong here, but I used a button and styled the background image as the picture that I wanted. Here is my code. Any help is appreciated!

CSS:

```
button.openTS {
  float: right;
  background: url("/images/tslogo.png") no-repeat;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-width: 0px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  width: 23px
}

  button.openIRC {
  float: right;
  background: url("/images/irclogo.png") no-repeat;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-width: 0px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  width: 23px
}

div.toolbar {
  background-color: #D6D6D6;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-bottom-width: 10px;
  border-bottom-color: #000000;
  border-left-style: solid;
  border-left-width: 10px;
  border-left-color: #000000;
  border-right-style: solid;
  border-right-width: 10px;
  border-right-color: #000000;
  border-radius: 15px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="toolbar">
    <h4 class="toolbar">Toolbar:</h4>
    <button onClick="TSappear(); IRCdisappear()" class="openTS"></button>
    <button onClick="IRCappear(); TSdisappear()" class="openIRC"></button>
</div> <!--This ends the Toolbar Div-->
```

Here is a picture of what is happening:

If I add a height, this happens: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TovxK.png

This is what happens normally: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQVNs.png

Comment: Presumably this is a question about HTML + CSS, but you've tagged your question with neither?

Comment: Yes it is, I fixed my tags, thanks!

Comment: You forgot a closing semi-colon after `width: 23px`. You might also add a `height` attribute. The missing `height` is likely your issue.

Comment: @EmanuelElliott To show blocks of code in StackOverflow you need to have four spaces before each line and also  a blank line before the first line of code

Comment: Can we have the `.toolbar` rules also? I think that your problem lies there...

Comment: Sure check updated post in a sec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need to give your `.openIRC` class a height. Elements with background images will not size themselves like an `<img>` element. So your `.openIRC` item will only show the background image to it's tallest child element (probably text).

**[Demo Fiddle:](http://jsfiddle.net/badAdviceGuy/Wrg6w/1/)** for an example of what i'm talking about.

Comment: Thanks! That was the problem! Cheers!